# Full Linux installation on USB with Windows Storage

Tags: partitioning, windows, usb-drive

I hope i'm not making a duplicate question as you can never really tell no matter how hard you search, which is something that i did.

Anyhow, to be fully straightforward, i would like to install a linux distro onto a USB drive as full installation, not a live usb with persistence, AND have a general storage partition that can be accessed by both Linux\Windows based systems

Most questions that i've found here relate to Live Usb with persistence storage and not what i need, I know that the answer might be something very simple but at this point i feel like i have burned enough eye vision to ask this question so please help!

Comment: A regular Ubuntu installation on removable drives is a bit complicated, but possible. However, to my knowledge Windows is not able to properly handle USB drives with multiple partitions, or at least wasn't able to do so in the past...

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/q/16988/367990 for the part about installing Ubuntu to a USB drive.

Comment: the thing is, i am fully able to install Ubuntu onto my usb drive, but the only part im stuck on is the creating a shared storage space, i mean, mkusb seems to be able to do it when installing a Live distro with  persistent storage so there must be a way or something im missing